# Pass selected Object to Child

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a for:each for my opportunities.  When one of the opportunities are selected I want to set a variable to contain that specific opportunity. I know I can only pass a string so I can't just pass the entire opportunity.  How would I go about setting a variable to contain the opportunity here?  What I need to do is pass that opportunity to a child component.  thanks!!

Here is my for:each:

```
<template for:each={opps} for:item="opp">
                <tr key={opp.Id}>
                    <td><div onclick={getSelectedOpp} data-oppid={opp.Id}><a >{opp.Name}</a></div></td>
                    <td>{opp.Owner.Name}</td>
                    <td>{opp.StageName}</td> 
                    <td>{opp.CloseDate}</td>
                </tr>
            </template>
```

And once an opportunity is clicked, here is my getSelectedOpp

```
  /* JS method to get selected opportunity id */
getSelectedOpp(event){
    this.selectedOppId = event.currentTarget.dataset.oppid;
    this.bShowModal = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `target` instead of `currentTarget`, and use `Array.prototype.find` to get the entire record.

```
getSelectedOpp(event){
  this.selectedOppId = event.target.dataset.oppid;
  this.bShowModal = true;
  this.opportunity = this.opps.find(opp => opp.Id === this.selectedOppId)
}
```